# TinyProxy: blank screen

Tags: configuration, proxy, tinyproxy

I'm trying to serve some pages via TinyProxy.

When I change my Firefox proxy settings to:

localhost:8888 (yes, I'm using a tunnel), all I get is a white screen?

When I comment out the line:

```
Listen x.x.x.x (the address of my server)
```

I get a 403 error:

```
Access denied

The administrator of this proxy has not configured it to service requests from your host.
Generated by tinyproxy version 1.8.1.
```

At least I'm sure my tunnelling is working when I get this error...

However, can someone please help me with the configuration of TinyProxy?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That means that TinyProxy is working. Look further down to find the ACL configuration for tinyproxy. You need to tell it what IP ranges to accept.  From the [documentation](https://www.banu.com/docs/tinyproxy/1.7.1/man/man5/tinyproxy.conf.html):

```
Allow
Deny
The Allow and Deny options provide a means to customize which clients are 
allowed to access Tinyproxy. Allow and Deny lines can be specified multiple
times to build the access control list for Tinyproxy. The order in the config
file is important. If there are no Access or Deny lines, then all clients are
allowed. Otherwise, the default action is to deny access. The argument to
Access or Deny can be a single IP address of a client host, like 127.0.0.1,
an IP address range, like 192.168.0.1/24 or a string that will be matched
against the end of the client host name, i.e, this can be a full host name like
host.example.com or a domain name like .example.com or even a top level domain
name like .com.
```